# Get old messages after bot reboot (Discord bot, NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord Bot and I have some issues. 
I want a way to get all messages of a channel but, after bot reboot, he doesn't "see" the old messages.
Here is an example:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class nbMess extends commando.Command{
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'nbmsg',
            group: 'admin',
            memberName: 'nbmsg',
            description: 'Return number of messages in a channel'
        });
    }
    async run(msg, args){
        msg.channel.send(`Number of messages : ${msg.channel.messages.size}`);
    }
}
```

So, I send 3 random messages, and after this, I boot the bot and launch the command.
And the result is 1, for the message that call the command.

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of your code.  Read this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it stands right now, we have no way to help you because we have no insight into what might actually be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.fetchMessages()` method to get messages sent in the past.

An example from the docs on [`.fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages):

```
// Get messages
channel.fetchMessages()
  .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

So your example would look something like this:

```
module.exports = class nbMess extends commando.Command{
    ...
    async run(msg, args){
        msg.channel.fetchMessages()
        .then(messages => {
            msg.channel.send(`Number of messages : ${messages.size}`);
        });
    }
}
```

You can pass an optional settings like a `limit` / max number of messages to return - see those settings here: [ChannelLogsQueryOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with discord.js, and found that discord.js-light does not rely on caching, and its events can be triggered on uncached objects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-light

There are some differences, and you may have to fetch some data that was otherwise automatically populated in discord.js.